# datagridview horizontal scroll bar is not allowing me to scroll to the last columns

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have an unbound datagridview that I am populating programically based on other criteria.  When the form first loads, the grid is empty. and grid have
horizontal scroll bar when i move scroll bar left 
to right it's not allowing to scroll the last column.

Comment: What container do you have for the grid. Try placing it in a panel if not already and choose "Dock In Parent".

Comment: currently i dont have any dock

Comment: Add a panel onto your form and resize appropriately. then cut your gridview and paste it into the panel. Click on the gridview and you will a little right arrow (like a play button) in the top right corner. Click on this and at the bottom you will see "Dock in Parent container".. click this and then see if you can scroll.

Comment: is there any other option available for fixed this instead of dock panel

Comment: Not off the top of my head. It seems like your grid is too wide for its container. Is there any reason why you wouldn't drop it in a panel?

Comment: because after grid i have some textbox other grids so i cant move on top or bottom

Comment: Try setting the "AutoSizeColumnsMode"  to Fill. There are a number of options.. so try a few.